# Default value data annotation for empty array

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a .NET Core Web API and want to call an endpoint submitting a customer order. The customer id comes as a route parameter. In the request body it's possible to send an array of objects. Each object contains the product id and its amount. But this field is optional, empty orders are possible too (products can be added later on).

So I started with this DTO

```
public class CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
{
    [FromRoute]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public OrderPosition[] OrderPositions { get; set; }
}

public class OrderPosition
{
    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint ProductId { get; set; }

    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint Amount { get; set; }
}
```

This request DTO should make the `OrderPositions` field optional but when adding an item both properties are required for that item. I want to set a default value for `OrderPositions` if missing so I thought this data annotation would do it

`[DefaultValue(new OrderPosition[0])]`

Unfortunately I get this error message

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, 'typeof()'
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

So how do you mark that field as optional and set a default value?

When passing no order positions the array will be transformed to an empty one so I can avoid null checks and work with loops that just never run

Comment: You can't do it using `DefaultValueAttribute`. But you can do it by introducing `OrderPosition[] _orderPositions = new OrderPosition[0];` field in the class and rewriting `OrderPositions` property as `get { return _orderPositions; } set { _orderPositions = value ?? new OrderPosition[0]; }`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your solution and changed it a little bit https://hatebin.com/osigtdckfz but for both ways when passing this body `{ "orderPositions": [{}] }` I get this error `An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size. at System.Array.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)`

Comment: updated comment code https://hatebin.com/nbrcqjrdmg

Comment: Can you use `List<OrderPosition>` instead of array?

Comment: not sure. I updated the code to https://hatebin.com/bsniqsostg This seems to work. But I would like to know the difference between this and this one https://hatebin.com/mykcqvgyaa When leaving the field it works too but when assigning `"orderPositions": []` then I get the error although it should just assign a new array instead of manipulating its length

Comment: Why not just consider `null` as default value?

Comment: because then I would have to perform null checks. I think an empty array avoids this

Comment: @Question3r depending on the parser being used, the reason the list works and not the array is because, if a collection already exists the parser will just add parses items to it. For an array the length is fixed and thus cannot be altered.

Comment: so I would have to go for this solution? https://hatebin.com/bsniqsostg

Comment: @Question3r If it works for you then I say yes go ahead. You indicated in a previous comment that it worked. I was just explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with arrays is that it has a fixed length. You can resize the array using `Array.Resize()` but that too needs a fixed length.

A better way is to use List instead of an array:

```
public class CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
{
    [FromRoute]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public List<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; set; }
}
```

By default, the list object `OrderPositions` will have `null` value; which is a good way to represent no items present in the list.

If you still need the list to be empty by default, instead of null, you can set the default value as below:

```
public List<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; set; } = new List<OrderPosition>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `List<OrderPosition>` instead of array. Then initialize it to empty list at constructor

```
public class CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
{
    public CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto()
    {
        this.OrderPositions = new List<OrderPosition>();
    }
    [FromRoute]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public List<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; set; }
}

public class OrderPosition
{
    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint ProductId { get; set; }

    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to hphp's answer, you can set a default value like you would with any c# class:

```
public class CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
{
    [FromRoute]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public OrderPosition[] OrderPositions { get; set; } = new OrderPosition[0]; // auto-initialize it here. 

    // alternatively you can use a constructor, but I prefer setting the property like above
    public CreateCustomerOrderByIdDto
    {
        OrderPositions = new OrderPosition[0];
    }
}

public class OrderPosition
{
    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint ProductId { get; set; }

    [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
    public uint Amount { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't like those ideas and you are using Newtonsoft.Json, you can also take advantage serialization events, and perform the default value setters on those as well: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem was that I get this error then `Collection was of a fixed size`. I think I can't use an array for this if I don't want it to be nullable